# Collect values in set from different columns in pyspark

Tags: pyspark

I have a table with 4 different indicators (string columns).

| ID | DATE | primary_ind | secondary_ind | third_ind | fourth_ind |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2019-12-12 | CODE1 | CODE2 | neither | CODE2 |

I want an output with an extra column as the set of the 4 indicator columns.

I know how to do it in python but in pyspark I have tried so far anything I know with no success. I tried creating udf that computes the set of columns but I get an "Out of memory" error. The input of the udf is to concatenate the four indicator columns separated by the delimiter.

| ID | DATE | primary_ind | secondary_ind | third_ind | fourth_ind | total_ind |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2019-12-12 | CODE1 | CODE2 | neither | CODE2 | [CODE1,CODE2,neither] |

Comment: Try using `collect_list`. Presumably that should suffice your requirement. Here is its [official documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.collect_list) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Have you can try Vector Assembler?

https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.3/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.ml.feature.VectorAssembler.html

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.ml.feature import VectorAssembler

sparkSession = SparkSession.builder.appName("Hello").getOrCreate()
df=sparkSession.read.option("header", True).option("inferSchema", True).csv(Your path)
total_ind=['primary_ind','secondary_ind','third_ind']
vectorAssembler=VectorAssembler(inputCols=total_ind,outputCol="total_ind")
newDF=(vectorAssembler.transform(df).cache())
```